# Handling notification alerts that fire when the app is not running, but still show when the app is running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, uialertview, uilocalnotification

Let's say my app is running in the background, and I receive 2 local notifications at the same time.  Alert1 for Notification1 shows, then Alert2 for Notification2 shows on top of Alert1.  When I tap "View" for Alert2, my app enters the foreground, and `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called for Notification2, everything is all good.

However, Alert1 is still showing (since it was never closed or viewed).  If I tap "View", nothing happens and as expected, `didReceiveLocalNotification` for Notification1 is NOT called.

Is there a way to either:

1. clear all Alerts so that Alert1 is not shown when the app is entering foreground for Alert2
2. handle the tap for "View" when Alert1 is pressed, since `didReceiveLocalNotification` is not called

Thanks!

Comment: Two alerts displayed at the same time?  Can you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: The second alert is displayed over the other, so only one is visible, though the other still exists underneath it.  If I tap "View" on the first alert, didReceiveLocalNotification is called and the app is entered into the foreground.  The first alert disappears, and the second one is now visible.

Comment: Calling `cancelAllLocalNotifications` also dismisses currently displayed alerts, even if the notification has already fired.

It's mentioned in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide:
_You can cancel a specific scheduled notification by calling cancelLocalNotification: on the application object, and you can cancel all scheduled notifications by calling cancelAllLocalNotifications. Both of these methods also programmatically dismiss a currently displayed notification alert._

Hence, I need to `cancelAllNotifications` and reschedule my current scheduled notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `cancelAllLocalNotifications` also dismisses currently displayed alerts, even if the notification has already fired.

It's mentioned in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13):

> You can cancel a specific scheduled
>   notification by calling
>   cancelLocalNotification: on the
>   application object, and you can cancel
>   all scheduled notifications by calling
>   cancelAllLocalNotifications. Both of
>   these methods also programmatically
>   dismiss a currently displayed
>   notification alert.

Hence, I need to `cancelAllNotifications` and reschedule my current scheduled notifications. I tried `cancelLocalNotification`, but I don't have a reference to the notification because it no longer exists in the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array since it has already fired.